# Export Keychain Items is not enabled from File menu of Keychain Access

Tags: keychain

As can be seen in the screenshot I have selected a bunch of keychain items. So why is `Export items` disabled?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only export one key at a time, or one key and a matching certificate.
It will be encrypted upon export and can only contain one key.

If you need to move an entire keychain to a different computer, look at ~/Library/Keychains - example login.keychain (in finder, cmd + shift + g, paste path, go)

It can be added to another machine and you can change the password of the keychain.

Comment: That's a v interesting idea about copying the keychain. I did that and it did not help.  Do you have any more details.?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Should be clear enough - read in the entries from the keychain.

Comment: Not clear enough for me though. What problems did you have by moving the keychain, it usually works just fine moving it to a different machine and/or user. Could you view all the items in the new machine/user keychain?

Comment: re: clarity: fair enough.  There was no effect when replacing the `login.keychain` from the second machine onto the first. The first did not show the entries contained in the overwritten file.

Comment: But if you just doubleclick the login.kechain that are copied you should be able to browse the content. Since you can store several keychain files on usb memories and other location than the original login placement. Replacing it require more things, first you cant replace a keychain if icloud keychain sync is active, secondly you cant be logged in as the same user as you replace the keychain for. Thirdly check the file permissions.

Comment: I have restarted a new keychain due to these issues and am not in a position to verify your latest suggestions.  I'm going to award in any case.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that only certificates can be ex-/imported, but not passwords.

You could copy and rename your keychain though, as described in [apple support document](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20120?locale=en_US). Then open "Keychain Access" and you will see your renamed keychain in there. Now you can copy/paste whatever item you want from one keychain to another (e.g. to your login keychain). Once you

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning to migrate keychains across machines, you could also use iCloud sync to get the keychain items on the other device/machine.

System Preferences - > iCloud -> Keychain

[image]